# Relating two angles under no slip condition

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: Disk rolling on circular ring]

Assuming the disk doesn't slip, is there a mathematical relationship between $\phi$ and $\theta$ ? I understand that as the arm rotates, $\theta$ increases proportionally to $\phi$, but I can't figure out the formula for $\theta$ in terms of $\phi$.

Comment: The wheel completes one rotation every $2\pi r$ units of distance.  And covers $2\pi L$ units of distance every time $\phi$ completes a revolution.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get what I need. Is it possible to determine a mathematical relationship between the two angles without knowing r and L?  Ideally, I need an equation for $\theta$ in terms of $\phi$.

Comment: $r\theta = {L} \phi$ or $\theta = \frac {L}r \phi$

Comment: @Matt Is your query answered by DougM's precise comment? What more elaboration do you need?

Comment: Yes, Doug answered my question.